# Update SQL to Datetime plus 20 minutes

Tags: mysql

how can I update SQL DATETIME to NOW()+20 minutes

I know I can convert the whole field to varchar and use `strototime` then add (1200) to the value but I want a direct method to add using NOW() in SQL

Comment: [`date_add()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: + INTERVAL 20 MINUTE

Answer (score 1):

Try with this below query.Hope it will be help you to solve your problem

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET updated_column_name = (
    DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)
);
```

Comment: @neville you'r welcome, if it did help you kindly upvote/accept so that others may see it as valid if they stumble upon this similar question it may help them too :) good day

Answer (score 0):

please try below command

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(mi,20, now());
```